# Rails, simple_from radio buttons

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style my radio buttons as they look awful. All tutorials require the structure to look like this

```
<span>
  <input>
  <label></label>
</span>
```

so that I can use css to select the checked radio button's label like this

```
input[type=radio] + label
```

Currently, I have

```
= f.input :product_size_id, collection: @product.product_sizes, as: :radio_buttons
```

which generates the input like this:

```
  <div>
    <span>
      <label>
        <input>
      </label>
    </span>
  <div>
```

I tried to find a way to select the input's parent using only css with no luck. 
How should I render my radio buttons or how to select the label of the selected radio button(The point is to use only css so no jquery)? Thank you!

Comment: I deleted my answer, but `label: false` must generate the `input` element without the `label` wrapper. Try restarting your server?

Comment: As in CSS3, there is **no parent selector**. If you need to select the parent of your input, you may add a class to the label preceding the input, or use a some JavaScript (jQuery or native JS if you can't use jQuery). 

Moreover, regarding your code, are you using a form helper or a form builder in your erb template? Your syntax is pretty weird, did you know there is a [rails helper for radio_buttons](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button)? Why are you using an input helper if you need a radio button?

Comment: I will go to the helper Ripley mentioned. Vucko, you were right that label: false should remove the label. It's that I expected that it would remove the outer label. This command removes the label that I was trying to get :D